# declaring elements of an array final (not just the array itself)

Tags: java, final

We can make an array final like this :`final int[] foo = <whatever>;`, but is there anyway I can ensure each element in that array is also final?

Comment: @sp00m No it's not...

Comment: Just because two questions SOMETIMES have the same solution, it NEVER means the two questions are the same!

Comment: @sp00m That question is about definsive copying. This one is about making objects unmodifiable.

Comment: That question asks: "how can I make this array immutable?". Is that not what you are asking?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14809293/1225328 `;)`

Comment: @sp00m I do not see the relation between this question and the one you posted.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well, in the end, both OPs want to have an unmodifiable array, am I wrong? One by implementing no setter, the other one by making it final.

Comment: @sp00m that won't work if you have the array as a local variable...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't possible with an array. However, for that you can use [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) instead:

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. This method allows modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists. Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the specified list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether direct or via its iterator, result in an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

This works well in conjunction with `Arrays.asList` as another answer has already indicated. So your array `foo` would be written as:

```
final List<Integer> foo = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, ...));
```

and instead of `foo[i]` you would use `foo.get(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but you can use an Unmodifiable List:

```
List<String> items = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("I", "can", "never", "change"));
```